# PHP скрипт не исполняется после AJAX запроса

Tags: php, ajax, cookie

Вопрос совсем не сложный, но не для меня.
Есть файл, в котором есть такая запись:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/php/ajax.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {inp:art, sum:sum, quant:quant},
    success: function(){
        $('.sum').text(sum);
        $('.goods_quantity').text(quant+'ok');
    }
})
```

Есть файл `/php/ajax.php` с единственной записью:

```
setcookie('ok', 'ok', time()+300);
```

Как сделать так, чтобы кука записывалась?

---

Куки есть, видно через var_dump после перезагрузки. Но надо вывести значение куки в браузер без перезагрузки. Что я не сделал?

Comment: заголовки ответа в студию тогда

Comment: а открывающий тег  `<?php`  в `ajax.php` есть?

Comment: Да, открывающий есть.
Заголовки на вкладке Network>All ? В Хроме

Comment: после обновления страницы кук так же нет?

Comment: Нет, после обновления и смотрю, но нет

Comment: почему бы не указать их средствами `JS`? или `php` обязательная часть?

Comment: Да, наверно можно и JS, но непонятно, что не так с PHP. Ведь одна строка кода и не работает

Comment: На всякий случай:
jQuery подключен, код в "success" исполняется, в консоли (Network>XHR) видно, что заголовок отправлен... вот тут оказывается и заголовки
************************************************************************
Set-Cookie:ok=ok; expires=Wed, 30-Aug-2017 20:38:47 GMT

Cookie:cart=ok; goods_quantity=0; sum=0; ok=ok;
***********************************************************************
Да, здесь кука есть, а почему тогда ее не видно при выводе кук через var_dump ?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно указать путь (четвёртый параметр)

```
setcookie('ok', 'ok', time()+300, '/');
```

иначе кука доступна только для страницы /php/ajax.php

Answer (score 0):

Кука не будет записываться в PHP, если запрос сделан не из бразуере пользователя, к сожалению это так, за то у самого Js есть функции `setCookie()`, которая в Ajax тебе может поставить куку, которая будет доступна соотвественно полномерно.